# Unable to access Pinterest search results

Tags: elasticsearch, web-scraping, pinterest

I want to access the pinterest search results upto 50 by using the pinterest api. May there are methods to **scrape** it from pinterest but I am unable to find it. So far I have got the pinterest users pins by using the method
doCORSRequest({
method: 'GET',

```
            //url: "https://api.pinterest.com/v3/users/ohjoy/"
            //const user-to-view: urlParams.get('myparam');
            //var mylink = "http://website.com/page.aspx?list=" + a + "&sublist=" + b;
            url: "https://api.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/users/user-name/pins/"

        }
```

An expert opinion is required to make it work for me.
thanks

Comment: you may need to put your username in the url like `https://api.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/users/ohjoy/pins/`

Comment: It will only return me the one user not the list of the users containing the search keyword.